# Sitecore OKTA Integration

Tags: login

Our System needs to Integration with OKTA SSO Provider. Here is the Problem statement

1)  OKTA is used as the IDP in Identity Management for performing SSO authentication.

2) Okta gets UserId and Password from Okta authentication screen and provides its configured URL to which it has to get redirected post authentication.

3) Post authentication of credentials in Okta, the context returns a token and same is added to the Claims

Now all the Internal users and admin will use OKTA for authentication for Sitecore CMS Login and all the Authorization, roles permission will be controlled by sitecore.

Can some body throw ideas on how this should be done.

Comment: Do you plan on using saml authentication or openId connect? Worth noting if using saml: http://jockstothecore.com/federated-authentication-with-shibboleth-2/

Comment: What version of Sitecore will you be using? Your version will dictate which integration path may be easiest.

Comment: We are using Sitecore 8.2 Update 2 . Could you please guide on the integration path do we have to use Custom Membership providers

Comment: Did you get chance to have a look at the solution where the integration is done using OWIN libraries? http://josedbaez.com/2017/09/sitecore-okta-login/

Comment: can you specify sitecore version? 8 and 9 are different

Comment: As Amit rightly pointed, have a look at  link http://josedbaez.com/2017/09/sitecore-okta-login/